# provide the code for colspan and rowspan?

Tags: html

[image]

expecting the code to for that image that i have attached

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_colspan_rowspan.asp happy reading

Comment: See [ask]. We're not a free code writing service

Comment: Hello, Stack Overflow is not a free program writing service website, so this question is not permitted. However, if you have any question when you are making the chart, you can post a post and we are glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create such a table, you'd need to implement the [`rowspan` and `colspan` attributes.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_colspan_rowspan.asp) `colspan` represents the number of columns a cell should span (to the right), and `rowspan` represents the number of rows a cell should span (downward). For instance, if I had a `<td colspan="2">` tag, the `td` element would take up the space of two columns. Here's an example of that behavior:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">This element occupies the space of two columns.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Utilizing `rowspan` and `colspan`, I was able to create code that generates a look-alike of the table you attached (CSS code solely for table visibility):

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="2">Average</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Red Eyes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Height</td>
        <td>Weight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Males</td>
        <td>1.9</td>
        <td>0.003</td>
        <td>40%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Females</td>
        <td>1.7</td>
        <td>0.002</td>
        <td>43%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```